# Symfony 4, Doctrine Innerjoin doesn't use junction table

Tags: symfony, doctrine, inner-join

I have two entities (entity1 and entity2) in a ManyToMany relation. All tables are working fine, if i just need the object from one entity. 
The fields in the entities are marked as ManyToMany including the mappedBy and reversedBy attributes.
I now need a subset from entity1 based on a where clause on entity2.

In SQL it's simple.

```
select
a.field1,a.field2
from entity1 as a
left join entity1_entity2 as b on a.entity1_id=b.foreignKey1
left join entity2 as c on b.foreignKey2=c.entity2_id
where c.whereField = 'value'
and a.whereField = 'anotherValue'
```

I want to use the Repository from entity1 and tried the query by the createQueryBuilder.

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('e1')
    ->distinct(true)
    ->innerJoin(Entity2::class, 'e2')
    ->where("e2.whereField2= :whereE2")
    ->andWhere('e1.whereField1= :whereE1')
    ->setParameter("whereE2", $whereE2)
    ->setParameter("whereE1", $whereE1);
```

The result looks like a full outer join. The dump of the DQL/SQL seems that no junction table is used. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You donn' have to specify the Entity in the innerJoin clause. Doctrine can do it by itself and use the join table too.

For example, entity1 as a ManyToMany annotation on the `secondEntities` property.

The queryBuilder may look like:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('e1')
    ->distinct(true)
    ->innerJoin('e1.secondEntities', 'e2')
    ->andWhere('e1.whereField1= :whereE1') // You can add additionnal conditions ;)
    ->setParameter("whereE1", $whereE1)
;
```

---

Note: You can use `ON` join condition like: `->innerJoin('e1.secondEntities', 'e2', Join::WITH, 'CONDITION HERE')`

Comment: -- old comment deleted --

Now i see and understand the difference from my DQL and your . Thanks!

Comment: If it helped you to resolve your problem. Don't forget to mark this answer as "answered" for future references ;)